# linux multithread scheduling

Tags: linux, multithreading, pthreads

I have a program launching about 12 threads on 8-core server. some of the threads are waiting for critical data. where it's using a recv in loop, the recv will block until data comes. However when there is data, it needs to process it asap.

one thing I noticed is that from time to from when the connection is quiet, the thread doesn't have much activity. the thread maybe put to sleep (suspect?), then when data comes in, it needs to wake up first, therefore wasting time. I'm wondering if there is anyway to set so the thread will not be put to sleep and wake up later? 
thanks!

Comment: That's the way these preemptive systems work - the thread calls recv() and blocks.  recv() returns when there is data, (or conn closed, or error).  Time is not wasted - while the recv() thread is 'sleeping', the CPU it would have used is available for other things, eg. running the network stack so that you get your data as fast as possible.

Comment: i see. as I have more threads than cores, will it cause contention? or should I only launch 8 threads on the 8 core server?

Comment: If you're just waiting for requests, processing them in a CPU-bound way, then responding, there's probably no point in more threads than cores. But if you are receiving a request, waiting on a non-CPU resource (say, local disk or sending a request to another server and waiting for a response), then more threads should help. Of course, you can always measure and know for sure in your environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not just your threads, there are other threads too. Within a large range it does not matter how many thread you actually have. Other threads are likely to get choosen by the scheduler while your thread is waiting on the `recv`. So when there is data to let your `recv` return your thread will get ready to run and *may* be choosen by the scheduler for execution. If all cores are occupied by threads of equal of higher priority than your thread and if their time slice not just luckely ends, your thread would have to wait for the cpu.
However, in order to get your thread scheduled **immedeately** after the `recv` has data, you should raise your threads priority. In this case the `recv` return will make your thread "runnable" and the scheduler will swtich to it before it considers any other threads of lower priority. If neccessary it will even stop a thread of lower prioriy of your thread.

Answer (score 2):

As Martin James said, blocking is a normal thing to do, whether through a simple `recv` or through `epoll` in an event-driven server. If you haven't observed a real measurable latency problem, I wouldn't worry about it. You're doing what everyone does.

And by real measurable latency problem, I mean a difference between your well-defined goal (say, 50% latency of 1 ms, 99.9%ile latency of 100 ms measured at the client under a certain load pattern, maybe bursty if you're concerned about blocking) and reality.

That said, I have heard of very latency-focused people [complaining](http://static.googleusercontent.com/external_content/untrusted_dlcp/research.google.com/en/us/people/jeff/Berkeley-Latency-Mar2012.pdf) about the kernel putting the processor in too deep of a [sleep state](http://software.intel.com/sites/manageability/AMT_Implementation_and_Reference_Guide/DOCS/Implementation%20and%20Reference%20Guide/default.htm?turl=WordDocuments%2Fsleepstates.htm) when there's not enough work to keep processors busy, causing too much latency on wake-up. I think this would be something you'd want to control at the kernel level, not your application. I don't see off-hand any numbers on the latency, so again this is something you'd want to measure: find (or create) a way to control the deepest sleep state it uses and measure the effect.